# HTML Javascript Automatic Window Scroll

Tags: javascript, html

Thanks in advance for any time you (the reader) spends to help me out and to understand what I am doing wrong. I am new to JS and HTML, and am teaching myself through the internet, so take this with a grain of salt. I might just not know enough and the answer is obvious to someone with more knowledge than me. :)

I am trying to make a simple (for now) "Hacking simulator" game that is command line based, with a custom HTML command line. You can view my full code (less than 500 lines) on GitHub:

https://github.com/qcontom/Hacking-Protocol

However, I have run into a slight problem, and cannot seem to find an answer that relates to my project on the web. I want to have my "terminal" window automatically scroll as the user enters in commands. The closest thing that I can find online to do this is:

```
const console = document.getElementById('terminal');

function scrollToBottom() {
    console.scrollTop = console.scrollHeight;
}
```

Where "terminal" is the HTML window that I want to automatically scroll.

What am I missing or doing incorrectly that causes the program to not scroll? Any help, or direction to a tutorial I might have missed, would be GREATLY appreciated!

Once again, thanks for your time!!

Comment: did you already try to run `scrollToBottom();` function when a user enter?

Comment: @MarkSalvania I did, I added it to the function that senses when the user hits 'enter' on their keyboard. It didn't change anything. :(

Comment: is it `console.scrollTop` ?, see this for more information regarding `scrollTtop` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)

Comment: @ChintuYadavSara I'm not sure what you mean... I already have the textarea defined, so I don't need  a new one. When the text that is entered overflows, I just want the textarea to automatically scroll to the bottom of the overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a `max-height` to your terminal element, otherwise it will not work. And to smooth the scroll add `scroll-behavior: smooth;`.

Elements doesn't create your own scroll bar unless max-height is defined and property `overflow: auto|scroll` is defined. And, if your content make overflow.

Elements without `max-height` forces `window` to create scroll, so you need to use `scrollTo` method from `window` object. Elements doesn't create your own scroll bar unless max-height is defined and property `overflow: auto|scroll` is defined.

Another approach is scroll the window, case your terminal has not max-height.
For this use:

```
window.scrollTo( {
  top: 300000,
  behavior: "smooth"
});`
```

```js
function scrollToBottom() {
  el = document.getElementById('console');
  el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight
  
  setTimeout( function() {
    window.scrollTo( {
      top: 300000,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  }, 1000 );
  
}
```

```css
#console {
  max-height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
p {
   height: 500px;
}

#scroll {
  min-height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="console">
  <button onclick="scrollToBottom()">Click Me</button>
  <p></p> <!--only to force scroll -->
</div>
<div id="scroll"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and willingness to help me out! This was the first one I tried, and managed to get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something like this, this would help I guess. It will work same as Terminal, it will focus on `textbox` when enter button is hit and asks to give a new command. You can make use of this if it helps.

```js
$(".panel").on('keypress', ".in", function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $(this).prop('readonly', true);
        var input = $(this).val().split(" ");
        if (input[1]) {
            var output = execute(input[0], input[1]);
        } else {
            var output = execute(input[0], "");
        }
        $(".output").last().html(output)
        $(".panel").append($("<div class='action'>").html("<div class='action'><div class='command'><span class='symbol'>$&nbsp;</span><input class='in' type='text'></div><div class='output'></div></div>"));
        $(".in").last().focus();
    }
});


function execute(command, parameters) {
    console.log(command, parameters);
    if (window[command]) {
        return window[command](parameters);
    } else {
        return "bash: " + command + " : command not found";
    }
}

$('.panel').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $(".panel")[0].scrollHeight
}, 800);
```

```css
.Terminal{
  background-color:black;
  color:lightgreen;
  width:300px;
  height:400px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
.Terminal panel{
  background-color:transparen;
  padding:10px;
  
}
.in{
  background-color:black;
  border:none;
  color:lightgreen;
}
.in:focus{
  outline:none;
}
::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
    color: lightgreen;
    opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="Terminal">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="action">
      <div class="command"><span class="symbol">$&nbsp;</span>
        <input class="in" type="text" placeholder="help" autofocus=""/>
      </div>
      <div class="output"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your time to put this together! I managed to get it working.